# What type of helicopter is this?

Tags: helicopter, aircraft-identification

[image]

Wondering what kind of aircraft this is. Military or commercial? Photographed nearing island HK (possibly near Wanchai) an hour or two ago.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That looks like a Harbin Z15 (aka AC352, Eurocopter EC-175, Airbus H-175).

This model isn't used by any military but [ones operated by the HK government](https://www.helis.com/database/modelorg/Hong-Kong-H175/photos) use a military-like color

[image]

[B-LVD (picture above) seem to have flown today.](https://www.helis.com/database/cn/45643/)

Comment: Looks  like you nailed it.

Comment: BTW, the past tense of "fly" is "flew" or "have flown".  So "B-LVD seem to have flown today".  I apologize on behalf of the English language to anyone that has to learn it.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yeah I was a bit hesitant on that but too lazy to look it up. Now I know "flied" is specific to baseball. Thanks.